# Numbers in Newcommand

Tags: macros, xetex

I have some thousands of special text lines specifically numbered.

```
001001=aaaaaaaa
001002=bbbbbbbb
001003=cccccccc

002001=dddddddd
002002=mmmmmmmm
002003=jjjjjjjj

003001=uuuuuuuu
003002=iiiiiiii
003003=vvvvvvvv
```

etc.

In my Latex file I want to insert that specific assigned text with a simple number entry such as `001001` or perhaps `\001001` , which in return will show `aaaaaaaa` once compiled. How can I do this?

Please note that I've already studied following Q&A's but still couldn't come up with a good result, not could I use `\catcode`. I use `xetex` and `polyglossia` if that makes difference.

- [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718/6621)
- [\newcommand gives errors in math mode (with or without arguments)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44545/newcommand-gives-errors-in-math-mode-with-or-without-arguments/44577#44577)

Comment: You would not be able to easily use `\001001` for a command. Would something like `\numentry{001001}` (that returns `aaaaaaaa`) be a possibility?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Please provide me with MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An approach without external packages can be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
001001=aaaaaaaa
001002=bbbbbbbb
001002=cccccccc

002001=dddddddd
002002=mmmmmmmm
002003=jjjjjjjj

003001=uuuuuuuu
003002=iiiiiiii
003003=vvvvvvvv
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newread\nina@read
\newcommand{\grabdata}[1]{%
  \begingroup\endlinechar=\m@ne
  \openin\nina@read=#1\relax
  \loop\ifeof\nina@read\else
    \read\nina@read to \@tempa
    \nina@convert
  \repeat
  \closein\nina@read
  \endgroup}
\def\nina@convert{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\@tempa}\relax\else
    \expandafter\nina@convert@i\@tempa\relax
  \fi}
\def\nina@convert@i#1=#2\relax{%
  \global\@namedef{nina@data@#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\numentry}[1]{\@nameuse{nina@data@#1}}
\makeatother

\grabdata{\jobname.dat}


\begin{document}

\numentry{001001}

\numentry{001002}

\numentry{001003}

\numentry{002001}

\numentry{002002}

\numentry{002003}

\numentry{003001}

\numentry{003002}

\numentry{003003}

\end{document}
```

I've used `\jobname.dat` as the file name just not to clobber my existing files.

If the data file is named `foo.xyz` you'll use

```
\grabdata{foo.xyz}
```

and then the data will be available in the form

```
\numentry{001001}
```

---

The data file is read line by line and each line is split at the `=` token to get the key and the value. So if the line is

```
001001=aaaaaaaa
```

we essentially do

```
\@namedef{nina@data@001001}{aaaaaaaa}
```

(globally, as we use `\endlinechar=-1` to avoid spurious spaces and get rid of empty lines).

Answer (score 10):

One way is to use [the `datatool` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool).
An attempt to print the values of `002003`, `001002`, and `999999` yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- I used `\IfStrEq` from the [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) package as I prefer it's syntax, but this can probably be done without that pacakge if desired.
- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) was used only to create a MWE to generate the data file `foo.dat`. It is not needed otherwise.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
001001=aaaaaaaa
001002=bbbbbbbb
001002=cccccccc

002001=dddddddd
002002=mmmmmmmm
002003=jjjjjjjj

003001=uuuuuuuu
003002=iiiiiiii
003003=vvvvvvvv
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\LocateDataRow}[3]{%
    % #1 = csname in which to store the required data
    % #2 = database to search
    % #3 = word to search for
    %
    \global\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{UNDEFINED}% Default in case it is not found
    %
    \DTLforeach{#2}{%
        \NumValue=NumValue,%
        \DataValue=DataValue%
        }{%
        \IfStrEq{#3}{\NumValue}{% 
            % Found an exact match!! Yeah
            \global\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{\DataValue}%
            \dtlbreak% Break out of for loop 
        }{%
            % Did not find match -- continue searching
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\DTLsetseparator{=}% Define separator of the data
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={NumValue,DataValue}]{myDB}{foo.dat}

\LocateDataRow{RequiredData}{myDB}{002003}\RequiredData

\LocateDataRow{RequiredData}{myDB}{001002}\RequiredData

\LocateDataRow{RequiredData}{myDB}{999999}\RequiredData
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution using `expl3` for parsing the data file. It uses a property list to keep the data in memory. Usage then means looking up the the key in this property list and displaying its stored value.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
001001=aaaaaaaa
001002=bbbbbbbb
001002=cccccccc

002001=dddddddd
002002=mmmmmmmm
002003=jjjjjjjj
foo bar
003001=uuuuuuuu
003002=iiiiiiii
003003=vvvvvvvv
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_ndata_line_tl
\tl_new:N \l_ndata_key_tl
\tl_new:N \l_ndata_value_tl

\prop_new:N \g_ndata_prop

% loading and parsing the data file

\cs_new:Npn \ndata_load_file:n #1 {
% opening a read stream
   \ior_open:Nn \l_ndata_ior {#1}
% loop until we see "eof"
   \bool_until_do:nn { \ior_if_eof_p:N \l_ndata_ior }
      {
% read one line of data into a variable
        \ior_to:NN  \l_ndata_ior \l_ndata_line_tl
% if the line has no "=" we skip it
        \tl_if_in:NnTF \l_ndata_line_tl {=}
            {
% if it has we parse (low-level, strange input is usually strange
               \exp_after:wN \ndata_parse:w \l_ndata_line_tl \q_stop 
               \typeout {line~ processed~ (\l_ndata_line_tl)}
            }
           {  \typeout {line~ without~ =~ ignored~ (\l_ndata_line_tl)}  }
      }
% close the stream as it is no longer needed
  \ior_close:N \l_ndata_ior
% showing the resulting property list (comment out in real use)
   \prop_show:N \g_ndata_prop
}

\cs_new:Npn \ndata_parse:w #1=#2\q_stop {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_ndata_key_tl {#1}
   \tl_set:Nn \l_ndata_value_tl {#2}
% remove any space to the left and right of key and value
   \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_ndata_key_tl
   \tl_trim_spaces:N \l_ndata_value_tl
% put the data into the property list
   \prop_gput:Noo \g_ndata_prop  \l_ndata_key_tl \l_ndata_value_tl
}

% using the data (instead of error handling for nonexistent keys I just used typeout)
\cs_new:Npn \ndata_use:n #1 {
   \prop_get:NnNTF \g_ndata_prop {#1} \l_ndata_value_tl
            { \l_ndata_value_tl }
            { ??? 
               \typeout{Warning:~ key~`#1`~ not~ known}
            }
}

% document level commands:

\DeclareDocumentCommand \ndataload {m} { \ndata_load_file:n {#1} }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \ndata     {m} { \ndata_use:n {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ndataload{foo.dat}

\ndata{002003}
\ndata{001002}
\ndata{999999}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for loading both `xparse` and `expl3` explicitly?  If not, then `\usepackage{xparse}` should be sufficient as it loads `expl3` for you I believe.

Comment: @ScottH. 
There is no technical reason. However, I like to load it as I want to emphasis that I use the programming layer of LaTeX3 AND (one of) its document user layers. In fact, given such a trivial user interface I could have shortened everything considerably by calling `\ndata_load_file:n` directly `\ndataload` thereby avoiding `xparse` altogether. But I wanted to show the general principle (and best practice) keeping the layers completely separate.

Comment: 10-4, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.  Thanks.