# Typing CO_2 easily

Tags: chemistry

I'm writing my dissertation and that involves typing a lot of `$\mathrm{CO_2}$`. I'd like to make a macro for it that's a lot easier to type, but if I put `\newcommand{\co2}{\mathrm{CO_2}}`, for example, it gives me the error that `\mathrm` can only be used in math mode. But using `\newcommand{\co2}{$\mathrm{CO_2}$}` doesn't work either.

Is there a way for me to make a macro that makes typing CO_2 easier, even if it doesn't use `\mathrm`?

Comment: Have you tried \newcommand{\cotwo}{\mathrm{CO_2}} see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44545/newcommand-gives-errors-in-math-mode-with-or-without-arguments also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393855/macro-shortcut-for-mathrm-command

Comment: For anyone new to latex reading this question: There are two separate issues here. One is that \mathrm can only be used in math mode. The second one is that you can't (usually) have digits in macro names.

Comment: Oh I did not realize you couldn't have digits in macro names! Cool, thanks!

Comment: About the digits: `\def\co2{CO$_2$} The level of \co2 in London is ....`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a question about how to use `\co2` as a macro name or just a question about how to subscript in text mode. If you use `\coo`, the macro

```
\newcommand{\coo}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{CO_2}}}
```

works fine in both text and math mode. If you're only planning to use the macro in text mode, `CO\textsubscript{2}` works.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\coo}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{CO_2}}}
\newcommand{\cooo}{CO\textsubscript{2}}

\begin{document}

With ensuremath: Text \coo\ and math $\coo$ both look fine.

With textsubscript: Text \cooo\ is fine, but math $\cooo$ isn't.

\end{document}
```

Don't forget the trainling `\` and space after the call in text mode.

Comment: Or use `\coo{}` in text mode, which avoids worries about the space getting eaten by something.

Comment: Especially when using macros, I think that using [xspace](https://ctan.org/pkg/xspace?lang=de) is really convenient. You put an `\xspace` at the end of your macro and it will decide if a space is necessary or not.

Answer (score 68):

You want easy?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\ch{CO2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For completeness, you might mention also `mhchem`

Comment: ChemFormula is part of the excellent [ChemMacros](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) suite by [clemens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5049/clemens). If you continue writing documents in the field of chemistry, I’d highly recommend spending some time skimming the documentation.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that `chemformula` (and I believe `mhchem`) are robust with respect to math mode (i.e., no need to modify the code inside vs. outside math environments.

Answer (score 33):

I would use the `mhchem` package. It makes a lot of chemistry things easier, including reactions as well as formulas.

Put the line

```
\usepackage{mhchem}
```

in the header section of your document, and then CO2 is just `\ce{CO2}`. You can use that in math mode or text mode, it works either way. Here are some examples of other formulae from the [package documentation](ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/.../mhchem/mhchem.pdf), to give an idea of what you can do. (Note from the very first example how easy it is to write a simple reaction.)

(Note also that, as mentioned in John Kormylo's answer, there is also a package `chemformula`. It seems to be very similar, and allows you to do the same things in very similar ways. It is a more recent package, but I have no experience with it.)

[image: examples]

[image: more examples]

[image: more examples]

[image: more examples]

Answer (score 3):

Using [`isotope`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/isotope/README) package with the macro `\cotwo` you can write easily and quickly `CO_2`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{isotope}
\newcommand{\cotwo}{$\isotope{CO}_2$}

\begin{document}

\cotwo

\end{document}
```